# 3D rendering for Ubuntu on VirtualBox

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, virtualbox, opengl

In Qt I have an error:

> GL version 2.1 with the gpu_shader4 extension is not supported by your
>   graphics driver but is required for the new OpenGL rendering backend.
>   Please update your OpenGL driver. If you are using Mesa please make
>   sure you have version 10.6.5 or later and make sure your driver in
>   Mesa supports OpenGL 3.2.

So how can I update OpenGL and Mesa in Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS on VirtualBox?

On guest:

```
glxinfo | grep OpenGL
```

> OpenGL vendor string: Humper
>
> OpenGL render string: Chromium
>
> OpenGL version string: 2.1 Chromium 1.9
>
> OpenGL shading language version string 4.40 - Build 21.20.16.4526
>
> OpenGL extensions:

On host I'm using Windows 10

Comment: Have you installed the Virtualbox Guest Additions in the guest OS?

Comment: Yes, I have installed this

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the output of `glxinfo | grep OpenGL` in the guest, and also in the host.